# "The application has stopped unexpectedly"- in case of google maps

Tags: android

I have this code for displaying map on android device but the following error is displayed in dialog box "The application Maps  (process com.example.maps) has stopped unexpectedly.". Even after following step by step procedure as given on developer.google.com/maps the above given error displays.

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/*  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}*/
}
```

here is the layout.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and here is the LogCat view.....

```
04-08 21:53:15.304:         D/AndroidRuntime(11290): Shutting down VM
04-08 21:53:15.304:         W/dalvikvm(11290): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught                                                                       exception (group=0x400205a0)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}:                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView     
(PhoneWindow.java:239)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290):    ... 11 more
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader       
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.maps-1.apk]
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView           
(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-08 21:53:15.304:         E/AndroidRuntime(11290):    ... 19 more
04-08 21:53:17.406:         I/Process(11290): Sending signal. PID: 11290 SIG: 9
04-08 21:53:34.072:         D/AndroidRuntime(11403): Shutting down VM
04-08 21:53:34.072:         W/dalvikvm(11403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught                                                                exception (group=0x400205a0)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable                               to start activity ComponentInfo   {com.example.maps/com.example.maps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView         
(PhoneWindow.java:239)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at com.example.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403):    ... 11 more
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader       
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.maps-2.apk]
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView           
(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-08 21:53:34.082:         E/AndroidRuntime(11403):    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use `MapFragment` in a project running on a device that is Android 2.3 or lower. To use Maps V2 on Android 2.3 and lower, you need to use the fragments backport from the Android Support package and use `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: I have tried this option but still the same error dialog persists.

Comment: @user1478588: Your stack trace should be different if you are correctly using the fragments backport (e.g., using `FragmentActivity`) and `SupportMapFragment`.